# What is the name of a graph like this, where the axes aren't uniform all the way along?

Tags: terminology, graphing-functions

Does a graph of this type have a name?

[image: IEE Regs BS88 Grpah]

When I say a "graph of this type" I mean where the scales on the axes aren't uniform all the way along.

Comment: May be [Logarithmic scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale) and log-log plot

Comment: The axes *are* uniform. Each tick mark represents an increase by a factor of ten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a name: It is a log-log plot.